# Normal Force Maximum Value

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Does Normal reaction force have maximum value for a given case of system(eg a boy standing on a surface)?
I searched for it on google but there was no answer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general maximum for the normal force. A normal force is a reaction force and it just has the magnitude that is required to hold back against whichever external force that is pushing on the surface.

But of course, in real life, any surface is made out of a material that has a certain non-infinite maximum strength. When the normal force, in order to hold back against an external force, has to be *larger* than what the material is able to supply, then the material will break. So in that sense, in reality there *is* a maximum for the normal force while there isn't in theory in ideal scenarios.